# How to show alerts/popups/windows using knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I think we shouldn't have references to html elements in viewmodel. So I think I can't do $('#id').dialog() or shouldn't do alert('message') or window.open().
Then how should I do it?

Comment: Take a look at this answer for a sample of using a custom binding to control a jQuery UI dialog from your view model.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs/8611892#8611892.  Setting an observable to true opens the dialog, setting it to false closes it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this answer for a sample of using a custom binding to control a jQuery UI dialog from your view model.

[integrating jquery ui dialog with knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs/8611892#8611892)

Setting an observable to true opens the dialog, setting it to false closes it.

Comment: Ok, you get 2 upvotes and accept :) Already upvoted original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using dialogs are no effort at all.  Just let Knockout do it's binding and the data will be in the dialog elements.  In my app, if the dialog is open or not has no effect.  Knockout will still update the values.

One consideration though, I do my bindings in logical sections.  So I would have the ko.applybindings apply to the main body of the page and the dialog separately in two calls.

With regards to alert's, you have to pass in the text to be displayed.  So to use knockout here, you would have to let knockout update a hidden element.  Then get the resulting value for display in your alert.

For window.open, not sure what your concern is.  As I understand it, that is the same as going to a new page.  So that page's logic would do the populating.

Comment: Yes I know that knockout will populate values in hidden dialogs. But how to show that dialog?

Comment: I'd like my viewmodel to contain only logic and no references to UI. So that I can test it independently of UI just like I can test business logic classes in Unit Tests written in C#. I can't test that my class opens window or shows alert I think.