# Recieving data from a dialog invoked via knockoutJS

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have learned how one can open jQuery UI dialogs via KnockoutJS custom bindigns as answered in this question: [integrating jquery ui dialog with knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs/8611892#8611892)

If my dialog has an input text field, how can I access data from it upon dialog close to alter the main view model based on the text filed contents? What is the general idea and even handler code place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. Just put an input in your dialog `div` with a value binding. Same as you would capture input from any binding. Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnPdE/167/) from that answer with an input binding.

```
<div id="dialog" data-bind="dialog: {autoOpen: false, title: 'Dialog test' }, dialogVisible: isOpen">foo dialog
    <input data-bind="value: dialogEntry" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! And what if I need to execute a function on my viewModel upon dialog closing? Do I do this via a dialog closing callback?

Comment: You could add a subscriber to your `isOpen` observable, its at the very bottom of this page: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 0):

Just make both fields bind to the same knockout js observable. Then they will always be the same values.

```
<a href="#popupLogin"  class="site_title" data-position-to="window"  data-rel="popup" data-bind="text:Title">

<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:Title" />
    </div>
```

When you change the text in the modal and click away or close it in some fashion you will see that the value in the other input will have changed as well.