# Knockout observable not always updating (video link within)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, observable

Video demo of problem: http://www.screenr.com/k168

- I click on the "y" button to fetch some data from the server.
- I click on the first result's "show details" link (**y-cof-dmx**) to show that records detail view - note the drug name (both in the modal title bar/data table and down in the console).  They all match.  So far, so good.
- I click the next result's "show details" link (**Yasmin 28**).  Note the drug name in the modal and console.  The console knows about the current model object but the modal doesn't get updated, it's still the "old" result, **y-cof-dmx**.
- Same thing for next result (**Yaz**), still shows the "old" result in the modal.
- I edit the drug name in the modal - it gets updated throughout the UI and is reflected when I pop open the modal again.

My observable is getting updated, just not all the time.  I'm not sure why this is.

All my code is up at http://jsfiddle.net/6fm5T/ though it will not run in the fiddle.

Interesting parts of the code, the modal can be found looking for:

```
<!-- start modal: drug details -->
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
```

And in the JS, there is:

```
//show details in modal
viewModel.showDetails = function(obj) {
    //add/update currently selected drug
    viewModel.selectedItem(obj);

    console.log(viewModel.selectedItem().drugName());

    //show modal dialog
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
};
```

Where I am trying to update the observable which is declared just a handful of lines above showDetails:

```
selectedItem: ko.observable(),
```

The data I'm dealing with are simple objects, the structure can be seen at the top of the JavaScript pane at http://jsfiddle.net/Gm64C/2/ (ignore everything else there).

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

---

**UPDATES FROM MY FIRST COMMENT BELOW**

Here are the pertinent parts of my revisions. In the html, I had to invoke drugName as a function:

From this:

```
<!-- start modal: drug details -->
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    <div id="dialog" data-bind="jqDialog: {title: drugName}">
```

To this:

```
<!-- start modal: drug details -->
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    <div id="dialog" data-bind="jqDialog: {title: drugName()}">
```

Here is my new custom KO binding for the jquery UI dialog:

From  this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqDialog = {
init: function(element) {
    //console.log('jqDialog init');
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
        $(element).dialog('destroy');
    });

    //setup modal dialog options - details view
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 850,
        height: 500
    });
},
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    //console.log('jqDialog update');
    var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor());

    //console.log(options);

    if (options) {
        //console.log('jqUpdate options');
        $(element).dialog(options);
    }            
}
};
```

To  this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqDialog = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        modalDefaults = {
        autoOpen: 'false',
        closeOnEscape: 'true',
        modal: 'true',
        width: '850',
        height: '500'
    };

    $.extend(options, modalDefaults);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $(element).dialog(options || {});
    }, 0);

    //handle disposal (not strictly necessary in this scenario)
     ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
         $(element).dialog('destroy');
     });
},
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
     var shouldBeOpen = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible);
     $(element).dialog(shouldBeOpen ? 'open' : 'close');
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is *probably* the combination of jQuery dialog and knockout.js. When jQuery creates a dialog, it performs operations on the DOM-tree. These operations *may or may not* conflict with Knockout.js, who also operates on the DOM-tree. Without a working jsFiddle it is difficult for me to confirm this, but my guess is that your problem lies there.

I see you already use a custom Knockout.js binding that wraps around jQuery dialog. Try replacing the binding with the one from this question's accepted answer:

[integrating jquery ui dialog with knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs)

Comment: Hi Martin, that other binding did work, but I had to tweak it slightly.  First, it wouldn't work with my $('#dialog').dialog() call in the init.  What I ended up doing is declaring a modalDefaults object within the revised init.  I have to have string values for the property values.  I then have to copy those properties onto the options object.  Oh, in my html, I had to invoke drugName as a func, jqDialog: {title: drugName()} It feels really weird to do this, do you have any ideas how to clean this up?  I'll post up the revised bits above so it's clearer.

Comment: Hi Magenta. Good to hear you are making progress. You have to invoke drugName as a function, because in Knockout, all observables are functions. I know this seems weird at first, but this is a fundamental property of Knockout.js. The reason is that not all browsers support JavaScript getters and setters (* cough * IE * cough *), so for compatibility, ko.observable objects are actually functions. If you ever encounter the situation where you do not know whether a variable is an observable or not, you can use ko.utils.unwrapObservable to retrieve the value.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the observable/function aspect, but I didn't have to invoke drugName as a function in my previous version, that's what I'm not understanding.  I also can't call $(element).dialog() in this latest binding's init, but I could in my previous version.  In my latest I have to copy over default settings into my init options object, which isn't a big deal, but feels not as clean.

Comment: The change from 'drugName' as a variable to an observable is probably caused by knockout mapping. Did you use mapping in the previous version? Your latest version seems like an improvement over the previous version to me. Good job :) Is the `setTimeout` required by the way?

Comment: Yep, used the mapping plugin in the previous version as well.  The timeout seems to handle the init method being called twice, once by dialog() the other by applyBindings().  This is mentioned in the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs