# ko.toJSON($root,null,2) return error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to debug ko (version: 2.2.1) using `<pre>` tag:

```
 <pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($root,null,2)"></pre>
```

but I'm getting this:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Object object has no method 'getType';
Bindings value: text:ko.toJSON($root,null,2)
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems like the $root object is actually the windows object, why is it happening, how can i make sure it remains in the scope of my ViewModel?

The scenario is like this:

I have a view that contains also a popup template. When a user clicks a button the popup shows and that is when I get this error (the $root looses the ViewModel scope and becomes the window object).

**VIEW:**

```
        <a  href="#" class="caspButton" data-bind="visible: editMode(), click:setEditMode">Done</a> 
        <!-- ko if: entities().length > 0 -->
        //THIS OPENS THE PROBLEMATIC POPUP
        <a href="#caspPopupAddEntities" class="caspButton caspPlus" data-bind="visible: editMode(), click:bindPopup.bind($root)"></a>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: parentChildArr().length > 0 -->
        <a href="sp/book/addChildEntity" class="caspButton caspPlus"  data-bind="visible: editMode(),cafeHrefParam: {entity: 'entity',st:'st',parentEntityType: parentTypeName,parentPropName:parentPropName }" title="Add Entity" data-cafeDialog="popup"></a>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <header>
            <h2 class="caspFancy" data-bind="text: $root.title"></h2>
        </header>

        <div class="caspData">
            <!-- ko if: entities().length > 0 -->
            <ul data-bind="foreach: entities">
                <li data-bind="css: {caspEditable: $root.editMode(),caspListSeperator: !$root.editMode()}"> 
                    <a class="caspDelete caspPosition" href="#removeEntities" title="Delete" data-bind="visible: $root.editMode(),click: $root.bindPopup"
                    data-delete="true"></a>

                    <div class="caspInnerData">
                        <a class="caspBookLink" data-bind="attr: {href: 'sp/book/book' }, cafeHrefParam: { chapter: 'chapter', page: 'page', id: $data.id }, text: name,css: {caspBullet: !$root.editMode()}"></a>

                        <!-- ko if: shortDescription -->
                        <p data-bind="text: shortDescription"></p>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .caspInnerData -->
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko if: parentChildArr -->
            <ul data-bind="foreach: parentChildArr">
                <!-- ko if: children().length > 0 -->
                <li data-bind="css: {caspEditable: $root.editMode()}"> 

                    <div class="caspInnerData"> 
                    <div class="caspParent"> 
                        <span data-bind="text: $root.parentTypeName"></span> :
                         <a data-bind="attr: {href: 'sp/book/book' }, cafeHrefParam: { chapter: $root.parentTypeNamePlural, page: 'page', id: $data.id }, text: parent" class="caspBookLink"></a> 
                     </div>                   

                        <ul data-bind="foreach:children">
                            <li>
                                <a class="caspDelete" href="#removeEntities" title="Delete" data-bind="visible: $root.editMode(),click: $root.bindPopup"
                                data-delete="true"></a>

                                <a data-bind="attr: {href: 'sp/book/book' }, cafeHrefParam: { chapter: 'chapter', page: 'page', id: $data.id }, text: name" class="caspBookLink caspBullet"></a>                             
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <!-- end .caspInnerData -->
                </li>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /ko -->                

        </div>
        <!-- end .caspData -->

//HERE IS THE PROBLEM - '$root' becomes the windows object when i open this popup
 <div id="caspPopupAddEntities" data-role="popup" class="popup">
            <div class="caspBtnWrapper"> 

                <a href="#" data-role="button" class="caspButton cafeRight" data-bind="click:$root.saveEntity.bind($root)">Done</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" class="caspButton cafeLeft" data-bind="click:$root.cancel">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            <!-- end .caspBtnWrapper -->
            <header>
             <h1 class="caspFancy">Add New</h1>

         </header>
         <div class="caspDataWrapper" data-bind="with:$root.addItem()">
            <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" data-bind="value:name"
                />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="shortDescription">Overview</label>
                <textarea class="caspTextarea" type="text" name="shortDescription"
                id="shortDescription" data-bind="value:shortDescription" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="mission">Mission</label>
                <textarea class="caspTextarea" type="text" name="mission"
                id="mission" data-bind="value:description" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="period">Period</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="  Set date and Time" name="period"
                id="period" data-bind="value:periodName" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="ownedBy">Owned By</label>
                <input placeholder= "Select" type="text" name="ownedBy" id="ownedBy" data-bind="value:ownedBy,cafeAutoComplete: {source: 'users'}">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="assignedTo">Assigned to</label>
                 <input placeholder= "Select" type="text" name="assignedTo" id="assignedTo" data-bind="value:assignedTo,cafeAutoComplete: {source: 'users'}">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <!-- end .caspDataWrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- end #caspPopupAddEntities -->



</div>
<!-- end content -->
</div>
<!-- end page -->
```

**VIEWMODEL:**

```
  /**
 * The module for the common Entities ViewModel
 */
define(['ko', 'komap', 'kopost', 'ca', 'sp/utils', 'sp/db'], function (ko, komap, kopost, ca, util, db) {

    /**
     * The Entities ViewModel.  This VM just exposes a collection of entities in a single property.
     * The model to retrieve is obtained from the last portion of the URL path.
     */

    function EntitiesViewModel(ctx, data) {
        this.init(ctx,data);

    }

    // EntitiesViewModel.prototype = new ca.ViewModel({});

    // EntitiesViewModel.prototype.constructor = EntitiesViewModel;

    ko.utils.extend(EntitiesViewModel.prototype,(function(){



        init = function(ctx,data){
            var self = this;
            strategyId = ctx.param.st;
            entitySet = db.getEntitySetFromElementType(ctx.param.entity);
                parentEntitySet = _getParentEntitySet(entitySet);                      
                childPropName = util.getChildEntityPropertyName(parentEntitySet);

            self.editMode = ko.observable(false);
            self.entities = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.parentChildArr = ko.observableArray([]);   
            self.users = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.parentPropName = util.getParentEntityPropertyName(entitySet);
            self.parentTypeName = util.getParentTypeName(entitySet);    
            self.parentTypeNamePlural = util.getPluralName(self.parentTypeName);

            self.title = ko.computed(function () {
                // temporary method to get the plural name.
                return util.getPluralName(entitySet.collectionName);
            });

            self.addItem = ko.observable(entitySet.addNew());
            self.addItem().name = ko.observable("");
            self.addItem().shortDescription = ko.observable("");
            self.addItem().mission = ko.observable("");
            self.addItem().period = ko.observable("");
            self.addItem().ownedBy = ko.observable("");
            self.addItem().assignedTo = ko.observable("");

            _loadData(self);
        },



        bindPopup = function (o, e) {
            openPopup(o, e);
            selectedEntity = o;
            var popupId = $(e.target).attr('href');
            ko.applyBindings(self, $('#overlay').find(popupId).get(0));
            db.User.toArray( this.users );
        },



        startEdit = function (o, e) {
            self.editMode(true);
            e.stopPropagation();
        },

        cancel = function (o, e) {  
            closePopup(o, e);
            this.addItem (entitySet.addNew());
        },




        saveEntity = function (o, e) {
            var self = this;
            var parent = parentEntitySet.addNew({ id: strategyId });
            parentEntitySet.attachOrGet(parent);

            var entity = {
                name: self.addItem().name,
                shortDescription: self.addItem().shortDescription,
                description: self.addItem().description
            }

            entity[self.parentPropName] = parent;

            var newEntity = entitySet.addNew(entity);
            entitySet.attachOrGet(newEntity);
            entitySet.add(newEntity);

            db.saveChanges().done(function (i) {
                closePopup(o, e);                               
                _loadData(self);
                self.addItem (entitySet.addNew());
                kopost.publish("ca.sp.entitiesChanged", "Add new Entity");

            }).fail(function (error) {
                self.addItem (entitySet.addNew());
                console.log('Error = ' + error);

            });

            //detach the entities after save to avoid having them saved again
            entitySet.detach(newEntity);
            parentEntitySet.detach(parent);

            e.stopPropagation();
        };


        return {
            init: init,
            setEditMode: setEditMode,
            bindPopup: bindPopup,
            cancelDelete: cancelDelete,
            startEdit: startEdit,
            cancel: cancel,
            deleteEntity: deleteEntity,
            saveEntity: saveEntity
        }

    }()));
    return EntitiesViewModel;
});
```

Comment: Can you show your ViewModel and where you call ko.applyBindings?

Comment: @namkha87 -  This is part of a large application and the applyBindings happens in an external controller element. I'll post the view and vm but they are quite big so i'll try to trim the irrelevant parts

Comment: Can you try it with the latest KO v2.2.1?

Comment: @nemesv - Sorry i typed the wrong version. I am using the latest, updated question.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: There's a lot of code missing here that could cause this issue. It's possible that your 'popup' code is changing the order of elements in the DOM.

For example, I have no idea what's happening in openPopup(o, e); but possibly that's where your problem lies.

Comment: All it does is attach an overlay layer to the body and display the popup on top of it (like Jquery UI Modal dialog). the popup is already designed via css (absolute position etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`$data` refers to the current item in the context.  A simple `ko.toJSON($data)` should show you the results.

Comment: In your view model's `bindPopup` method, there's a reference to `#overlay` (`ko.applyBindings(self, $('#overlay').find(popupId).get(0));`)  Make sure that an element with that id exists in your DOM. If it's being put there by a framework then you will need a custom binding to make it work with knockout.  Here's an example of that with jQuery UI's dialog:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8611892/182875