# Error with latest knockout and jquery ui dialog: cannot call prior to initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I try to use with knockout 2.2 custom binding new jquery 1.9 and jquery ui 1.9.2. 
Code is from here: [integrating jquery ui dialog with knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs)
With updated libraries: http://jsfiddle.net/SnPdE/323/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
            //do in a setTimeout, so the applyBindings doesn't bind twice from element being copied and moved to bottom
            setTimeout(function() { 
                options.close = function() {
                    allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible(false);                        
                };

                $(element).dialog(options);          
            }, 0);

            //handle disposal (not strictly necessary in this scenario)
             ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                 $(element).dialog("destroy");
             });   
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
             var shouldBeOpen = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible);
             $(element).dialog(shouldBeOpen ? "open" : "close");

        }
};


var viewModel = {
    label: ko.observable('dialog test'),
    isOpen: ko.observable(false),
    open: function() {
       this.isOpen(true);   
    },
    close: function() {
       this.isOpen(false);   
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Problem is error: Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

If I remove setTimeout - applyBindings is applyed to dialog two times.

Comment: seems to work fine simply removing the `setTimeout` http://jsfiddle.net/SnPdE/325/

Comment: But then applyBindings will be applyed two times to dialog.

Comment: not sure where idea comes from that `applyindings` is applied two times

Comment: Simple. Place button and label, which will show button clicks (clicks stored in observable variable). You will see, that clicks is counted twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if the dialog is initialized before calling `open` will fix it.

```
if ($(element).data('dialog')) {
    $(element).dialog(shouldBeOpen ? "open" : "close");
}
```

The initial `update` is not required at all, as the dialog will be opened during initialization if `autoOpen` is `true`, which is the default.

**Edit:**
To be correct when the `dialogVisible` is initially `false` a change should be made to set the `autoOpen` option.

```
...
options.autoOpen = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible);
$(element).dialog(options);
```

Comment: I dont understand - your change works fine in jsfiddle, but don't works in my production code :-( $(element).data('dialog') is allways undefined. I hate "find three differences" style problems :-((( jquery 1.8.3, jquery ui 1.10, knockout 2.2.1.

Comment: Found it at last. I think jquery ui maked some change and so: $(element).data('uiDialog')