# How to control and bind to multiple jqueryUI dialogues from Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to be able to control n jqueryUI dialogues from Knockout

I've seen how you can control dialogues from knockout here:
[Error with latest knockout and jquery ui dialog: cannot call prior to initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707312/error-with-latest-knockout-and-jquery-ui-dialog-cannot-call-prior-to-initializa)

In that post the dialogue is controled in the update handler :

```
 update:ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible);
              $(element).dialog(shouldBeOpen ? "open" : "close");
```

Is there any consensus how you would control the state of multiple dialogues with observable like so:

```
  isAddOpen: KnockoutObservableBool = ko.observable(false);
    isEditOpen: KnockoutObservableBool = ko.observable(false);

    openEditDialogue(editingItem) {
        this.editingItem = editingItem;
        this.isEditOpen(true);
    }
    closeEditDialogue(editingItem) {
        this.editingItem = editingItem;
        this.isEditOpen(true);
    }

    openAddDialogue() {
        this.isAddOpen(true);
    }
    closeAddDialogue() {
        this.isAddOpen(false);
    }
```

I could repeat the logic with another binding handler but I would prefer to stick to just the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding deals with opening/closing a dialog specific to the element that contains the binding. So, you can place a binding on separate elements that maps to different booleans:

```
<div data-bind="dialog: {autoOpen: false, title: 'Dialog test' }, dialogVisible: isOpen">dialog</div>

<div data-bind="dialog: {autoOpen: false, title: 'Dialog test 2' }, dialogVisible: isOpen2">dialog 2</div>
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RvH6L/

Comment: this is simply 1st class!!