# prevent submit button with jquery ui dialog combined with knockout if statement

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an issue where I'm using the KO if tags to bring dialog code into the DOM when requested.  On the dialog is a form with a submit button.
I wish to prevent the submit button from submitting using e.preventDefault();
The trouble lies that on document load because the dialog is not in the DOM this over-ride function is not working.

I've created a JSFiddle here to demonstrate the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/rZBhx/4/

```
model = new function () {};
model.functions = ko.observable();
model.data = ko.observable();
model.data.status = ko.observable("Status: model is live");
model.data.visible = ko.observable(false);

model.functions.showDialog = function (dialogVisible) {
    if (dialogVisible == true) {
        model.data.status("Status: Darth Dialog Activated");
        model.data.visible(true);
        $("#darthDialog").dialog({
            modal: true
        });
    } else {

        model.data.status("Status: Darth Dialog Deactivated");
        $("#darthDialog").dialog('close');
        model.data.visible(false);
    }

};

ko.applyBindings(model);

$(function preventSubmit(e) {

    $("#submissionForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        model.status("Status: Saved by Ko.da");
        return false;

    });
});
```

As a side note, in my fiddle the cancel button only works once with the ko if statements.
I'm not sure why this is.   In my live site this isn't happening.
If you remove the 
  
from the HTML then the submit is prevented, and the cancel button continues to work.

Is there someway this can be made to work, whilst keeping the KO if's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do is to use a `submit` binding on the `form` element inside of your block. Then, when it is visible (bound), the submit handler will be attached to the current DOM elements.

`<form action="/darkSide/submission" data-bind="submit: submitForm" id="submissionForm" method="post">`

Then, just add a `submitForm` function (or whatever you want to call it on your model).

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gDkXf/

You may also want to take a look at using a custom binding to encapsulate the logic around the jQuery UI dialog.  Take a look at this answer: [integrating jquery ui dialog with knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs/8611892#8611892)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed thanks - I was unaware of the submit binding