# JQueryUI dialog as bindable template in KnockoutJS

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, dialog

This question is exposing that one: [integrating jquery ui dialog with knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs/)

I have Model with array of items like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([])
}

viewModel.items.push(new DialogModel("title 1"));
viewModel.items.push(new DialogModel("title 2"));
viewModel.items.push(new DialogModel("title 3"));
```

Next I show these items in markup using `foreach` statement

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div data-bind="text: title"></div>
    <button data-bind="click: open">Open</button>
    <button data-bind="click: close" >Close</button>
</div>
```

I need to show JQueryUI dialog on clicking buttons and this dialog **should be binded** to ItemModel instance.
I do not want to include dialog code inside loop because it is copying in result DOM and makes it **huge**. I'd like to use dialog in template for example.

JSFiddle mockup here http://jsfiddle.net/YmQTW/8/

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array that contains only the opened dialogs and bind this array to the template.

With this code only dom of opened dialogs are duplicated.

```
var DialogModel = function (title) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.isOpen = ko.observable(false);
    self.open = function () {
        viewModel.shownDialogs.push(self);
        setTimeout(function () { self.isOpen(true); }, 0);
    };
    self.close = function () {
        this.isOpen(false);
    };
    self.isOpen.subscribe(function () {
        if(self.isOpen() === false)
            viewModel.shownDialogs.remove(self);
    })
};

var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([]),
    shownDialogs: ko.observableArray([]),
};
```

The view :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: shownDialogs">
    <div data-bind="template : 'tmpl'"></div>
</div>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YmQTW/12/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't like the idea with additional array, also your implementation has two issues: 1. dialog showing inplace (not on the middle of the screen), 2. Dialog Button Close isn't works.

But finally I figured out this thing, working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tVjAD/