# ko.bindinghandlers.with fails in IE8

Tags: knockout.js

I have a custom binding for integrating the jQuery UI Dialog widget based on  Ryan Niemeyer's answer for this: [integrating jquery ui dialog with knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs/8611892#8611892).

After the call to the Dialog widget I want to bind the "with" binding, something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.annotatePanel = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 840,
            resizable: false,
            close: function() {
                var data = valueAccessor();
                if (ko.isWriteableObservable(data)) {
                    data(null);
                }
            }
        });
    },0);

    //ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { 'with': valueAccessor() }, bindingContext);
    //ko.bindingHandlers["with"].init.apply(this, arguments);
    ko.bindingHandlers.with.init.apply(element, valueAccessor(), allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
```

This works fine in Chrome and FireFox but in IE8 I am getting the following error:

**"Expected identifier..."**

If I change the code to use either:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {'with': valueAccessor()}, bindingContext);

or

ko.bindingHandlers["with"].init.apply(this, arguments);
```

I am not getting any errors.

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that "with" is a keyword for IE.

Could someone advice if this is a known problem?

Thank you

Comment: You got it right. Old IE throws errors when you try to use reserved words as property names.  Using ['with'] is an appropriate fix.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this Ryan. On a side note, love the work you do with the Knockout team and your active contribution to the KO community.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan stated,

If you need IE compatibility, don't use reserved words as property names. A workaround is to use the following syntax:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['<bindingName>'].init....
```