# Why can't we call uniform() before applyBindings()?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js, foreach, uniform

When we use Knockout with UniformJS and call `.uniform()` before `ko.applyBindings` the code below does not work?

Html code:

```html
<div id="myContainer">
    <div data-bind="foreach: teste">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" /> My checkbox
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$("input").uniform();    // Call here... does not work!
function vm() {
    var that = this;

        this.teste = ko.observableArray([
            { id: 1, 'value': '1' },
            { id: 2, 'value': '2' },
            { id: 3, 'value': '3' },
        ]);    
}

ko.applyBindings(vm());
//$("input").uniform();    // Call here... works fine!!!
```

However, if we call it after `ko.applyBindings` everything works normally. Why is that?

See the issue live in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5133t1p/11/).

Comment: I guess you should use <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: someObservableProperty" />

Comment: Ohhh.. Sorry... yes... <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: someObservableProperty" /> but, even so, the visual state of my control is not changed.

Comment: Jeroen, i have improved the question and put the code in JSFiddle. Thank your for your help!!

Comment: Have you checked if you are seeing any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Yes, i checked, no error is displayed on the console, just like the control is not checked visually.

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h5133t1p/12/

Comment: When we called the uniform() after applyBindings() works well, the problem is: Because when called uniform() before applyBindings() does not work the checkbox?

Comment: Aight, yes, now I understand the question! (PS. Don't forget to put an "@" if you reply to someone in a comment if you want them to be automatically notified.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout creates `input`s dynamically and adds them to the DOM. The uniform plugin can only work on existing elements. If you call `.uniform()` on `$("input")` before applyBindings there *are no `input`s*: the only input on the page is a template for the three inputs that are generated by KO.

I suggest you use a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to handle this task:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uniform = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).uniform();
    }
};
```

This can be used like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="uniform" /> My checkbox
```

You can also change the binding to take in more parameters and start calling it like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="uniform: { wrapperClass: 'myClass' }" />
```

Here's a [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/h5133t1p/18/), though you should also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611892/419956) for a more robust implementation of passing options like that to your binding.

Added advantage of all this would be that you can steer uniform's behavior from your view models, which in turn makes everything more testable.

---

PS. One alternative that may also be applicable is using the `afterRender` bit of a [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) binding.

Comment: thank you for complete and clear answer, that's exactly what I needed.   
PS: Thanks for the tip about '@'.