# load modal with reference number using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, knockout.js, modal-dialog

a js file which loads a invoice model, and I want to display all the information from the invoiceviewmodel for a certain reference number. This is the knockoutjs invoice file code

```
        self.selectedinvoice = ko.observable();



/* Vew model for username data */
    function selectedInvoiceViewModel(root /* root not needed */, invoice) {


        var self = this;
        self.ID = invoice.ID;
        self.currency = invoice.currency;
         alert("here i am in selected invoice view model");
    };

    /* Gets the details for a single reference  */
    self.getSelectedInvoice = function (selectedinvoice) {



        self.selectedinvoice(selectedinvoice); 

        self.showMOdalRf();
    };
```

So now I am trying to load all the data from the selectedinvoiceviewmodel with a certain reference number to my view file which looks something similar to this.

```
<div data-bind="bootstrapShowModal: modalRfDetails" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-bind="click: hideModalRf">×</button>
            <!-- bindauksen voi tehdä joko pelkästään ID tai pidemmän kaavan mukaan $data.ID -->
            <h4 >Details for Invoice  </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
               <thead>
            <tr>

                <th class="text-center">invoice description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="with: selectedinvoice">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td><span data-bind="text:ID"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Currency</td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: currency"></span></td>
            </tr>
```

So basically my idea is, when someone clicks the reference number in the table which is given in this way

```
<td class="text-right"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getSelectedInvoice"><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></a></td>
```

The model should pop open and get the all the data from InvoiceViewModel for just that reference number only.

Examples, click the [reference number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5irQ.png) and modal opens up with all details like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj1uE.png)

Comment: well i didn't get much but if you want to load data for particular reference no on click , try passing that as a parameter on click which loads the data `click: $root.showModalRf($data,rf_reference)` .

Comment: its basically if I click the reference number, the model should contain all info from the reference number, I added two pictures at the end so you can see what I mean the modal doesnt show anything now, and I did try your parameter but doesnt work. @supercool

Comment: sadly i can't see those (access issues) but still the above mentioned way is the way to go . you seem to say you tried ? on click you pass the reference number to click function in viewModel there you need to query to get data for that particular ref no and fill it in `selectedinvoice` . still does't work it may be problem with your view binding . #suggestion use `with:selectedinvoice` on tbody and simply use `text:ID` avoid using `selectedinvoice().ID` etc 'redundant stuff

Comment: You should start by learning the basics: use observable properties in your models, use `with` binding, use a binding for showing the modal (by addign the corresponding class to the modal element). Please, make the http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ tutorials. Then you'll have more clear whhat you have to do. On the other hand, you shpuld simplify the question by showing only a few of the viewmodel properties. We don't need to see the whole object to understand the problem.

Comment: @supercool
I made few changes to my post and edited it,but I still cant open the model for some reason.

Comment: @JotaBe I did use with binding now, and made few changes but doesnt open the model.

Answer (score 0):

The best and more idiomatic way to control the opening or closing of a widget, is by creating a custom binding.

Here you have a dialgo binding made by R P Niemeyer: [integrating jquery ui dialog with knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs)

This solution uses jQuery modals. Perhaps you'll have to adapt it [to use bootstrap modals API](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v1.4.0/docs/javascript.html). The solution will be quite similar.

It's much better to do it this way, than directly using jQuery. That's a bad idea because you're mixing up two very different ways of interaction with the DOM elements: direct manipulation, and MVVM binding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, from the name of your binding handler, that you used [this bootstrap modal binding handler](https://gist.github.com/ssajous/6057088). Unfortunately, it has at least one typo. But it's at least a good start.

When you have a particular problem, like a modal won't open for you, write a minimal example program. Don't include anything that's not relevant to the problem you have. In this case, all you should have is a modal and something to control it. That's not just for our benefit, that's how you can solve your own problems. Clear away all the other code that might interact in unpredictable ways with your issue.

So here's some example code using that binding handler (corrected). All I did was grab an example HTML for a Bootstrap modal, hook it up to the binding handler, and make a button to toggle the modal controlling variable.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapShowModal = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    $(element).on('hidden', function() {
      value(false);
    });
    $(element).on('shown', function() {
      value(true);
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    console.debug("New value:", value);
    if (value) {
      console.debug("Opening");
      $(element).modal('show');
      // this is to focus input field inside dialog
      $("input", element).focus();
    } else {
      console.debug("Hiding");
      $(element).modal('hide');
    }
  }
};

vm = {
  isOpen: ko.observable(false),
  toggleOpen: function() {
    console.debug("Toggling");
    vm.isOpen(!vm.isOpen());
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="bootstrapShowModal: isOpen" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: toggleOpen">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some correction made from the above answer. In the above code toogle button need to be clicked twice to make it open since it is not updating isopen observable on closng the modal.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapShowModal = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    $(element).on('hidden', function() {
      value(false);
    });
    $(element).on('shown', function() {
      value(true);
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    console.log("New value:", value);
    if (value) {
      console.log("Opening");
      $(element).modal('show');
      // this is to focus input field inside dialog
      $("input", element).focus();
    } else {
      console.log("Hiding");
      $(element).modal('hide');
    }
  }
};

vm = {
  isOpen: ko.observable(false),
  toggleOpen: function() {
    console.log("Toggling " + vm.isOpen());
    vm.isOpen(!vm.isOpen());
    console.log("Toggling1 " + vm.isOpen());
  },
  closemodal: function() {
    vm.isOpen(false);
    console.log("Toggling2 " + vm.isOpen());
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="bootstrapShowModal: isOpen" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-bind="click:closemodal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-bind="click:closemodal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: toggleOpen">Toggle</button>
```