# HTML content appears at first outside of jQuery UI dialog

Tags: html, jquery-ui, knockout.js

HTML:

```
<div id="printCardModal">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- ko foreach: employees -->
        <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
          <td><input class="input-medium"></td>
          <td><input class="input-medium"></td>  
          <td><input class="input-medium"></td>    
          <td><input class="input-medium"></td>         
        </tr>  
      <!-- /ko --> 
    </tbody>
  </table> 

  <button  data-bind="click: printCard"> 
    Print
  </button>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
   self.printCard=function(){
     $( "#printCardModal" ).dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        resizable: true,
        maxHeight: 600,
        width: 1000,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Create PDF": function() {
            ... 
          },
          Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
     });  
   };
```

I am not writing everything of course. The above HTML is just a part of the main HTML. My problem is that the **content of thead** appears in the main HTML page at first and only if the dialog modal opens does it take it (the content of thead) from the main page and renders to the dialog modal.
However, everything is okay with the content of the observable array employees which appears inside modal only. What do I have to do as for everything inside **#printCardModal** appears only when the dialog modal opens?

Comment: When you need to manipulate the DOM with something that's not Knockout, you need a custom binding handler. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8611892/392102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#printCardModal {
  display:none; 
}
```

It was so simple!!