# KnockoutJS dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Hello everyone i've a question.I have application with knockout JS and java , when i click an icon for open a dialog form it isn't opened. The code of js is :

```
this.pageStates = {
            view: 0,
            showDetails: 1,
            mpshowStagingDetails: 2,

};



this.mpShowDetails = function () {
                backoffice.viewModels.ajaxOverlay.showLoader();
                backoffice.viewModels.ajaxOverlay.hide();
                self.pageState(self.pageStates.mpshowStagingDetails);
};
this.pageState = ko.observable(this.pageStates.view);



this.mpdetailsStagingIsVisible = ko.computed({
            read:  function() {
                return self.pageState() == self.pageStates.mpshowStagingDetails;
            },
            write: function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    self.mpShowDetails();
                } else {
                    self.hideDetails();
                }
            }
        });
```

in the jsp the code is:

```
<div id="offerCreditDetails"
     class="details" style="display: none;" data-bind="dialog: { prop: mpshowStagingDetails , title: 'title', cssClass: 'role medium'}" >

     <jsp:include page="../views/mp_offerCredit.jsp" />
</div>
```

Comment: The `dialog:` binding is not part of knockout - what is providing this binding?

Comment: jquery-ui providing this binding

Comment: jQuery UI is probably supposed to be doing the end result, there will be something else providing the `dialog` binding that links knockout to jquery UI.  Or perhaps there isn't, and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611327/integrating-jquery-ui-dialog-with-knockoutjs

Comment: not work with this method