# JQuery dialog using typescript/knockout not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout and typescript to open a dialog based on a conditional.  The if statement works, but the dialog doesn't get toggled using the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TypeScript:

```
class SearchMTRModel {
    mtrWarnElement: JQuery;
    allowDuplicates : KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
 }
```

- Initialize function :

  ```
  var model = new SearchMTRModel();

  $(() => {
  ko.applyBindings(model);
  search();

  model.mtrWarnElement = $('#mtrWarnDialog').dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              modal: true,
              title: 'Duplicate MTR detected.',
              buttons: {
                  'Cancel': () => {
                      model.allowDuplicates = ko.observable(false);
                      model.mtrWarnElement.dialog('close');

                  },
                  'Confirm': () => {
                      var heats = new MTRHeat();
                      model.allowDuplicates = ko.observable(true);
                      addPDFToPackage(heats);
                      model.mtrWarnElement.dialog('close');
                  }
              },
          close: () => {
              model.allowDuplicates(false);
              model.allowDuplicates = ko.observable(false);
              model.mtrWarnElement.dialog('close');
              }
      });
  });
  ```

The function that is supposed to open the dialog :

```
export function addPDFToPackage(heat: MTRHeat): void {


    var koHeat: MTRHeatWithInclude = ko.mapping.fromJS(heat);
    koHeat.Include = ko.observable(true);

    var mtrID = koHeat.MTR.MTRID();

    var mtrIDs = [];

    var addToHeats = () => model.mtrPackage.Heats.push(koHeat);

    var arrayOfHeats = model.mtrPackage.Heats();
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfHeats.length; i++) {
        mtrIDs.push(arrayOfHeats[i].MTRID());
    }
    var idx = mtrIDs.indexOf(mtrID);

    if (idx >= 0) {

       //the code gets here but dialog doesn't open.

       model.mtrWarnElement.dialog('open');
    } 
    else if (idx === -1 || model.allowDuplicates()) {
       addHeatToPackage(model.mtrPackage.PackageID(), heat.HeatID).done(addToHeats);
        } 
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mtrWarnDialog" data-bind="dialog: { autoOpen: false, modal: true}">

</div>
```

Comment: In your HTML what does your custom binding do? data-bind="dialog: {autoOpen:false, model:true}". It looks like you're manually calling .dialog() in your initialize anyways so I'm not sure why you'd need both.

Answer (score 1):

The listed code is very unclear, as the code that should open the jQuery dialog, seems to be triggered by the confirm-button inside the dialog.
Aside from that, you also seem to have a dialog-BindingHandler in your HTML code, which isn't listed here.

---

The approach I've used in the past, goes as follows.

Add a property onto your components ViewModel, which indicates if the dialog should be shown or not

```
public showModal: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.observable(false);
```

Add a BindingHandler for the jQuery Modal-dialog. There are plenty of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611892/2149093) of this on stackoverflow.
Make sure to register the BindingHandler, or it will have no effect.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.modal = ...
```

In your template, hand the public property from your ViewModel to the BindingHandler, something like:

```
<div data-bind="dialog: { dialogVisible: showModal }"></div>
```

Finally, set the property on the ViewModel to true/false and the modal should open/close.

```
this.showModal(true);
```